# How can I create forms that send email in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email, wordpress-theming

I'm new to PHP and WordPress. I've been searching for this since an hour and I've found some solutions but they either do not fit or I couldn't set them up.

I have a contact form and another form which has values changed with javascript as user clicks to some buttons. So I don't know how to integrate Contact Form 7 to this.

I tried wp_mail() and it didn't work.

I am using XAMPP localhost, is that the reason why they do not work?

When I fill the form and click submit, same page reloads but either page cannot be found (same link just query strings added) or page is blank white.

How can I successfuly send emails containing form information in WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option for you:

#### Use Contact Form 7 + your JavaScript code

**1. Create a form in Contact Form 7**

[image]

**2. Write your JavaScript code to handle the input value**

In Contact Form 7 you can custom form's HTML so, you definitely can integrate with your JavaScript by your own ID, class.

**3. Setup email**

In WordPress, to able to send an email, you should configure the email that use to send

**Install plugin [Easy WP SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/)**

**Add email to config** I usually use a Gmail with the [App password](https://devanswers.co/create-application-specific-password-gmail/)

[image]

In conclusion, you can simply test the Send mail function with step 1 + 3.

Comment: Thanks. Why is page being white or cannot be found after submit button is clicked and page is refreshed?

Comment: It should stay on the same page as normal. The page is refreshed when submitting a Contact form 7 usually because of conflict in javascript of CF7 with other js.